# Running app built in iOS4 on iOS 3.0, why is everything huge?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My background and my icons are all huge, like it's zoomed in 2x. Any ideas why?

Comment: It sounds to me like you only have one set of images at the @2x resolution, and are not using the @2x naming convention. The result would be UIImage loading the high resolution image regardless of the device it's running on.

Comment: Could it be that your app was built for iPhone 4's 960x640 resolution and you are somehow running it on a device with only 480x320 max resolution?

Comment: It could be. I'm unsure how to correct that though.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the apps in iOS 4 are targeted for iPhone/iPod 4 which have a resolution of 960 x 640, whereas iOS 3 has a resolution of 480 x 320. Do read about [Retina Display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4#Display) of iOS for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Check the images in the app- there should be two sets of images, with one set being at double resolution and suffixed with "@2x". If there's just one set and they seem large, odds are the developer never intended the app to be run on a device that's not running iOS4 (which seems odd, but there it is).